# Objective C: Download Thread not affecting UI, even possible?

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, cs193p

I'm working through the Standford course on ItunesU and there they say a thread to download something should not do anything to the UI, this should only happen on the Main Thread.

Well, in my example I'm downloading a picture from Flicker and I want to setup this picture (via a segue) in a `UIScrollView`. So while I'm downloading this picture in the "side" thread I'm setting the image property of the `UIScrollview` to image etc. However this doesn't work obviously, because I don't know the imagesize yet and I also don't have a reference to that image object yet to set right?

So how do you handle that? I hope I'm clear..here is my example:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(NSIndexPath *)sender{
NSDictionary *selectedPhoto = [self.photos objectAtIndex:sender.row];

    [self.defaults addPhotoToRecentlyViewed:selectedPhoto];
    [self.defaults saveDefaults];

    PhotoViewer *photoViewer = segue.destinationViewController;

    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    photoViewer.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:spinner];
    [spinner startAnimating];

    dispatch_queue_t photoDownload = dispatch_queue_create("photoviewever", nil);

    dispatch_async(photoDownload, ^{        
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[FlickrFetcher urlForPhoto:selectedPhoto format:FlickrPhotoFormatLarge]];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        photoViewer.image = image;

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            photoViewer.title = [selectedPhoto objectForKey:FLICKR_PHOTO_TITLE];
            photoViewer.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
        });
    });
}
```

and my PhotoViewer:

```
#import "PhotoViewer.h"

@interface PhotoViewer ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

@end

@implementation PhotoViewer

@synthesize scrollView = _scrollView;
@synthesize imageView = _imageView;
@synthesize image = _image;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.scrollView.delegate = self;
    [self setupImage];
}

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    return self.imageView;
}

- (void)setupImage{
    self.imageView.image = self.image;
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.image.size.width, self.image.size.height);
    self.scrollView.contentSize = self.image.size;
    [self.imageView setNeedsDisplay];
}

@end
```

Comment: So what is your problem? Can you get the image and display it on your UIScrollView?

Comment: Well not really. When I change the setter of the image in the photoViewer and only do the setup there, I'm able to display it yes. However the scrolling doesn't really work and when I go back to the image from another tab it's completely scrolled out and doesn't work at all.

I'm just wondering how this threading should work. Because in my download thread I set the photoViewer.image to the downloaded image, but only after the image was downloaded.

However the references in the PhotoViewer are set before the image is downloaded…so I'm a bit confused..how should this be done?

Comment: I dont feel it is a good idea to download an image inside prepareForSeague method. Why dont you download it, when the view has loaded completely. And of course you could override the setter method in the new view controller and see if it really loaded and then set the image.

Answer (score 0):

You should move this line:

```
        photoViewer.image = image;
```

into the "completion" block you dispatch back to the main thread. PhotoViewer appears to be a view controller, and as such it's subject to the same "main thread only" rules as other UI. Also, it looks like you'll need to call `-setupImage` again from that main thread "completion" block. (Otherwise the image will never get pushed into the image view, as you noted.)

Also in `-setupImage`, you want to check that `self.image` returns a non-nil value before addressing into it. Depending on which compiler you're using, the behavior of calling a struct-returning Objective C method is 'undefined' (i.e. self.image.size returns a CGSize struct). (Although in recent compilers, it [returns a zero filled struct.](http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2012/2/29/objc_explain_return_value_of_message_to_nil.html))